# Iterative summations in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, zabbix

I have values in a Zabbix DB that are loaded onto it every minute. I need a query that computes hourly totals for different days e.g under 20 Mar 2013, I'd have a row for 0:00 containing a sum of values where time >= 0:00 and < 1:00 and so on. Then I'd have another row for between 1 and 2 AM etc. I am using the query below, but I have to keep changing the times. What I am looking for is a query that will generate for me 24 rows for each hour period in a day. Please help.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN itemid = 23661
        THEN value ELSE 0 END) Hits 
    FROM history_uint WHERE 
        clock >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2013-03-24 00:00:00')
         AND clock < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2013-03-24 01:00:00')
```

Comment: In the past with MSSql I've cross joined to a table containing numbers to act as an iteration index and then added time based on that number. Something like this `select adddate(hour, @date, NumbersTable.number) from NumbersTable`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grouping the results by the hour?

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp) [HOUR]
, SUM(CASE WHEN itemid = 23661 THEN value ELSE 0 END) hits 
FROM history_uint
WHERE clock >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp '2013-03-24')
  AND clock < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp '2013-03-25')
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp);
```

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" LINE 1: SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, timestamp) [HOUR], ^ ********** Error ********** ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" SQL state: 42601 Character: 34

Comment: This error is because of the function to extract the Hour part of the datetime column. Unfortunately, I don't know the appropriate function in postgre (this is from SQLServer), but if you know the right function, this solution should work. Please let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select '2013-03-20'::date + delta * '1 hour'::interval
from generate_series(0,23) g(delta)
```

Comment: This only generates the series of hours... how do you get it to give soemthing like a timestamp in one column and a count of values for that hour in a second column?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    date_trunc('hour', clock) "hour",
    sum((itemid = 23661)::integer) hits 
from history_uint
group by 1
order by 1
```

Or with all the hours filled:

```
select
    s.hour, count(itemid = 23661 or null) hits 
from
    (
        select date_trunc('hour', clock) "hour", itemid
        from history_uint
    ) h
    right join (
        select date_trunc('hour', d) "hour"
        from generate_series (
            (select min(clock::date)),
            (select max(clock)::date + 1) - interval '1 hour',
            '1 hour'
        ) s(d)
    ) s on s.hour = h.hour
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: I think date_trunc won't work with clock because clock is not a timestamp object but integer (epoch time)